# Random sequence of words "true" and "false" in python?

Tags: python, random

How to generate a random sequence made of words "true" and "false" in python (or python3)?

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `random` library and a generator

```
import random
(random.choice(("true", "false")) for _ in range(size_you_may_want))
```

Comment: @StefanPochmann, its a generator expresion, im aware of that i may not have choose the proper words, he can consume it with whatever he want. Ill edit :)

Answer (score 0):

you could try:

```
import random

values= ['true','false']
print(random.choice(values))
```

I hope this help you